# Why isn't pair<int, int> POD(Plain Old Data)

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

POD's definition: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/PODType

`pair<int,int>` seems to conform to all the rules above.

However compile & run

```
cout << is_pod<pair<int, int>>::value << endl;
```

gives me 0.

I'm using g++ 8.2.0

Comment: I'd wager it has something to do with the fact that it has a non trivial constructor, so it doesn't conform to all the rules.

Comment: In which mode you compile?

Comment: Citing [open-std: N2342: POD's Revisited; Resolving Core Issue 568 (Revision 5) - `std::pair` example](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2342.htm#std::pair-example): _"`std::pair<T,U>` isn't a class aggregate, since it has a user-defined constructor, and that means it also isn't a POD."_.

Comment: std::pair is a template and a special case of tuple, with constructors, specializations, and chocolate taffy, no? Hardly trivial.

Comment: Better use std::array<int,2> it is POD

Comment: @ChristopherPisz: `std::pair` is not a specialization of `std::tuple`.  The concepts may be related, but the templated types aren't.

Comment: @Ben I didn't say it was a specialization. I said it was a special case of. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair and see the description.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz: cppreference is just wrong about that.

Comment: @ben No,it really isn't. You are confusing a human description with words describing its source. Two different things. A Tuple: "An n-tuple is a sequence (or ordered list) of n elements, where n is a non-negative integer." A pair is that.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz: The concept "a pair" is a specific case of the concept "a tuple".  But that was not your claim.  Your claim, and the erroneous sentence on cppreference, involve C++ types not English language concepts.  `std::pair` is the name of a C++ type template; it is not a "human description" of a concept.

Comment: The standard describes a `std::tuple` with arity 2 as _"similar"_ to `std::pair`. Quoting [\[tuple.general/1\]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/tuple.general) [**emphasis** mine]: _"An instantiation of `tuple` with two arguments **is similar** to an instantiation of `pair` with the same two arguments"_. As for cppreference's "special case" description, this is arguably quite a leap from "similar".

Comment: @Ben  A "tuple" is a computer science concept. I'd love to argue about how you interpret the phrase in question all day, but we aren't helping the OP at all and I've got better things to do that pay me much better. Private message me if you'd like to continue this pointless debate.

Comment: @dfri thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Slava default for g++ 8.2, which is c++14